# Uploading image to Uploadcare.com using AlamoFire

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I'm not sure how to upload image using Alamofire to [Uploadcare.com (reference)](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/upload/#from-url). I should give path to image or binary array? I'm not sure is converting strings to `Data` object are correct

```
 func uploadPhoto(imageToUpload : UIImage){

        let keyJson = ("<my_api_key>").data(using: .utf8)!
        let uploadStore = "1".data(using: .utf8)
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUpload, 0.2)

        Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.append(keyJson, withName: "UPLOADCARE_PUB_KEY")
                multipartFormData.append(uploadStore!, withName: "UPLOADCARE_STORE")
                multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "file")
            },
            to: "https://upload.uploadcare.com/base/",
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        debugPrint(response)
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    debugPrint(encodingError)
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Result:

```
[Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6100002390a0> { URL: https://upload.uploadcare.com/base/ } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true;
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "X-PINGOTHER, DNT";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "POST, OPTIONS";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Access-Control-Max-Age" = 1;
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 31;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sun, 09 Oct 2016 18:41:45 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
    "X-Frame-Options" = DENY;
} }
```

Comment: Can you check response body? Uploadcare servers try to explain what is missing or is incorrect in the request: https://uploadcare.com/documentation/upload/#errors

Answer (score 0):

As I can see there are two ways you can do it with Alamofire. You can use functions taking file URL like `public func append(_ fileURL: URL, withName name: String)` and give them an URL to file. Or you can convert images to data and send with functions like `public func append(_ data: Data, withName name: String)`